# Call a python variable that runs a function which returns a variable for the original python variable

Tags: python, dynamic, properties, decorator

I'm trying to create a variable where when I call or use that variable, it runs a function to do stuff and return a certain variable. An example will make more sense:

```
def establish_client():
    a = None
    if True:
        a = 'A'
    return a


>>> print establish_client
'A'
```

It is possible to do this? Basically is there a way of running a method and returning something without using parenthesis?

Comment: Is there a problem with having to add an empty set of parenthesis to your item...?

Comment: Ultimately what i'm trying to do is create a global constant that each time it is called checks a connection to see if it exists and if it does returns the connection object. I want to save it in a variable rather than call the function each time

Comment: Why can't you simply do `global = method()` each time?

Answer (score 1):

In the general case: No.

But there are some techniques that might come close.

Properties allow something like that for members in an object.

```
class Demo(object):
    @property
    def establish_client(self):
        a = None
        if True:
            a = 'A'
        return a

d = Demo()
print d.establish_client
```

But properties don't work for local or global variables.

Also you can use `__str__` for to string conversion, but that only works when you only need this behavior when the variable is used in a way that converts it to a string. Which is usually not the case. See mescalinum answer for how to do that.

Comment: For a moment i thought that a crazy hack monkey patching a modules `__getattr__` or `__getattribute__` would possibly work. But is seems that cpython doesn't support that :)

Answer (score 0):

Note: the following is a hack, and there's probably more than a good reason to not do it.

---

You can achieve something on that line using a `class` and the `__str__()` method:

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def __str__(self):
        a = None
        if True:
            a = 'A'
        return a
```

Test:

```
>>> f=foo()
>>> print(f)
'A'
>>>
```

---

Beware: it works only with print and functions that explicitly treat arguments as strings.

For example, if you want to assign its string value to another variable, you have to use `str(f)` so you end up using parentheses.